# error: narrowing conversion from int to char al declarar una variable char

Tags: c++

```
char Especiales[9]={'!','¡','$','%','&','-','?','¿'};
```

[image: Esto es lo que me compila]

Comment: Por favor, salvo que sea imprescindible, no coloques imágenes. Las imágenes son difíciles de leer y no se pueden copiar/pegar en caso de ser necesario.

Comment: Si es que no sabia , como mostrar mi error, lo tendre presente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> no me reconoce como tipo `char` sino como entero

Eso es porque **no todos los caracteres pueden codificarse en un solo *byte***.

El estándar indica que todo compilador ha de soportar un conjunto mínimo de caracteres, todos ellos *codificables* en un solo `char`.

Sin embargo, el caracter `'¿'` **no pertenece** a dicho conjunto. Dependiendo del editor con el que creas el archivo de código, su configuración, y la configuración del sistema operativo, `'¿'` puede codificarse de diversas formas, la mayoría de ellas **ocupan mas de un `char`**.

La solución a esto depende tanto de la codificación del archivo como del compilador usado. `gcc` soporta la opción `-finput-charset=charset` para indicar la codificación del archivo fuente; otros compiladores tienen opciones similares. Si estás obligado a usar `char`, es tu única opción disponible. Y no es sencillo de usar, puesto que has de guardar todo el código fuente en esa codificación.

Si no estás obligado a usar `char`, [hay otros tipos mas capaces](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) para tratar con estos problemas. A cambio, **suelen ser de mayor tamaño**:

```
wchar_t Especiales[9]={ '!', '¡', '$', '%', '&', '-', '?', L'¿' };
```

Observa el prefijo `L` para indicar la codificación.

A cambio, **no podrás usar nada relativo a `char`** para trabajar con esa variable. Tendrás que usar `std::wstring` para almacenar cadenas, `std::wcout` para salidas a consola, y `std::wcin` para entradas de usuario.

Además, tus problemas no terminan ahí. Con eso ya puedes trabajar con caracteres *anchos* ... otra cosa es **mostrarlos por pantalla**. Aquí entran en juego la configuración del programa emulador de terminal, o la configuración del propio sistema operativo.

Comment: Gracias , me compilo usando el wchar_t ...Aunque lo estudiare mas , estoy usando linux por cierto